# how do i make absolute positioned div behid it's relative positioned parent

Tags: css

I have this navigation menu and i want to make a part of second level menu( like 50px from its top ) go behind navigation wrap : like this photo :

[image]

```
<div class="main-nav-wrap wrapper">
    <nav class="inner-el container main-nav">
        <ul>            
            <li>
                <a href="" title="">Menu Item 1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu Item 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu Item 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Menu Item 1-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- .main-nav-wrap -->
```

and here is the css :

```
.main-nav-wrap{
  position:relative;
  z-index:4;
}

.main-nav > ul > li {
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.main-nav > ul > li > ul {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}

.main-nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

i'm trying to hide a part of `.main-nav > ul > li > ul` behind `.main-nav > ul > li > ul`
please help , thanks
fiddle added : http://jsfiddle.net/p91pdwLd/2/

Comment: did you try removing the `z-index` from the parent element?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to demonstrates the problem or a link to the site?

Comment: yes i have tried removing z-index and position:relative; from all parents , but still nothing :(

Comment: ok @Alek , i will create a fiddle

Comment: here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p91pdwLd/2/

Comment: Thx but this one doesn't demonstrates the problem :P

Comment: @Dornaweb No, don't remove position:relative; from parent element on only remove z-index. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tf9fy8pb/1/) - notice that the absolute child is under the parent

Comment: oh my god , thank u so much @Danield , It Worked , thanks again <3 http://jsfiddle.net/p91pdwLd/5/

Comment: @Dornaweb - no probs - I just posted an answer - feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` from the parent element

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tf9fy8pb/1/)** of this:

### Markup

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background: aqua;   
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    background: maroon;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```